# Create an instance, I already have the type

Tags: python

```
class ClassA: pass
mytype = type(ClassA)
```

Using `mytype`, how do you create an instance of `ClassA`?

Note that I'm *NOT* looking for this as my answer :)

```
instance = ClassA()
```

I know that in this example, that's all you need to do but suppose that you have this type (`mytype`), you don't know anything about it, and you need to create an instance of it.

I tried just calling `mytype()` and it returns an error stating that type() takes 1 or 3 arguments.  I imagine these arguments may be related to any arguments you'd want to pass into the init method of the object being created.

Note: I've seen a number of questions asked about how to create an object given a string representing its fully qualified name.  Note that here, I already have a type so it's a bit different?  I think?

I had hoped that I could do the equivalent of the following .NET code:

```cs
class A {}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type type = typeof(A);

        // Given the type, I can create a new instance
        object new_instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

I had assumed that in Python, `type(ClassA)` gave something back that I could later use to create an instance of `ClassA`. Looks like I misunderstood type in Python.

Comment: mytype = type(ClassA) will give you a class object.  I suspect this is not what you meant.

Comment: It is what I meant, I think :)  See my edit above with the .Net example if that helps clarify anything.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you use a new style class it, this will work:

```
class ClassA(object):
    pass

o = ClassA()
mytype = type(o)
new_object = mytype()
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: ... But apparently not if you ahve parameters in `__init__()`

Comment: @Basic: What's the issue with parameters in `__init__()`? When I update `ClassA` with something like this: `__init__(self, a, b)`, then I can use the example above without any problems, just like `mytype(1, 2)` or `mytype(a=1, b=2)`.

Answer (score 4):

This question makes no sense. `type(X)` tells you the type of `X`, and the return value contains no information about the spesific class `X`, in the same way `type("abc")`, which is `str`, contains no information about the string used as argument.

Unless the class `X` has a custom metaclass, the answer will always be `type`, since that is the default metaclass in python. In your case then, `mytype is type`, that is, they are the same object.

You can use `type` to check the type of an object if you use one argument, or using three arguments you can create a class dynamically,:

```
myclass = type('ClassB', (object,), {"class_attribute": 3.14})
```

Let's assume for a moment that `mytype` worked as you thought it would. Remember that an instance of a type is a class, in exactly the same way that an instance of a class is an object. So, in the same way that (except for singleton classes) `ClassA() is not ClassA()` (each instance is unique), `mytype() is not mytype()` -- i.e. you should get a different class each time you instantiate the type. So you wouldn't get `ClassA` back anyway. To illustrate the point with code you can run:

```
>>> type('A', (object,), {}) == type('A', (object,), {})
False
```

**OP EDIT ANSWER**:

Classes in python are "first class citizens", unlike what you have in most compiled languages. This means you can pass the class around directly; you do not need a `typeof` equivalent:

```
>>> class A(object): pass
... 
>>> B = A
>>> B()
<__main__.A object at 0xb781138c>
>>> def print_class_name(cls):
...     print cls.__name__
... 
>>> print_class_name(B)
A
```

[This](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html) article contains an excellent explanation of how `type`, `object` and object instances are connected in python.

Answer (score 3):

Is lazyr says, it is not possible with `type`. Maybe what you could use is something like

```
class ClassA: pass
myclass = ClassA
instance = myclass()
```